# .htaccess do something else if file not exist

Tags: .htaccess

We are using an .htaccess in combination with anchor tags to serve files and conceal the server directory structure.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /_docu/clients/$1/$2/$3.pdf [NC,L]
```

For example, all files are stored under `/public_html/_docu/clients/` and inside that folder are listed all the clients, and then under each client their projects. However, an anchor tag for a file would read only:

`http://mydomain.com/client-name/proj-name/docname.pdf`

(the /_docu/clients/ being omitted - there is a good reason for this). The above .htaccess grabs the `client-name`, `proj-name` and `docname` and serves it from the correct folder:

`http://mydomain.com/_docu/clients/client-name/proj-name/docname.pdf`

whilst preserving in the address bar the incorrect (concealed) directory structure.

**I wish to handle the error condition of a document not existing.** This should never happen, but it could. Can anyone suggest a way of dealing with this? Can something functionally akin to "if fileexist($1/$2/%3.pdf)" be somehow constructed in an .htaccess file?

---

EDIT:

Delayed response as JL's answer below required research and experimentation. Thanks, Jon, for the gentle push in the right direction but I haven't got it to work just yet. Here's what I tried:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# check if the requested file exists in the "_docu/clients" directory
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/_docu/clients/$1/$2/$3.pdf -f
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9])/([a-z0-9])/([a-z0-9]*).pdf$ /_docu/clients/$1/$2/$3.pdf [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /errors/404.php [L]
```

I *thought* that what that should do is:

1. If `http://mydomain.com/_docu/clients/$1/$2/$3.pdf` does not exist,
2. GoTo page `http://mydomain.com/errors/404.php`

Actual outcome is an "internal server error" message.

---

EDIT TWO:

Latest changes:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([a-z0-9])/([a-z0-9])/([a-z0-9]*).pdf$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/_data/cli/%1/%2/%3.pdf -f
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9])/([a-z0-9])/([a-z0-9]*).pdf$ /_data/cli/$1/$2/$3.pdf [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /metshare/404.php [L]
```

The problem with this one is that legitimate pages also are directed to 404.php

MESSAGE TO FUTURE READERS:

All of the above concerns were addressed in Jon Lin's final answer. As issues were detected, he modified his answer until it was a perfect, working solution. I am leaving the above as it is because there are some good ULOs within (unscheduled learning opportunities) for those who want to compare versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a condition like this:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/_docu/clients%{REQUEST_URI} -f
```

So that your rules looks ssomething like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# check if the requested file exists in the "_docu/clients" directory
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/_docu/clients%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^ /_docu/clients%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

---

EDIT: Response to edit in question

You can't do this:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/_docu/clients/$1/$2/$3.pdf -f
```

Because the backreferences for $1/$2/$3 don't exist yet, they are matched in the groupings in your `RewriteRule`, which hasn't happened yet at this point. But you can try something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# check if the requested file exists in the "_docu/clients" directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([a-z0-9])/([a-z0-9])/([a-z0-9]*).pdf$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/_docu/clients/%1/%2/%3.pdf -f
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9])/([a-z0-9])/([a-z0-9]*).pdf$ /_docu/clients/$1/$2/$3.pdf [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /errors/404.php [L]
```

Essentially creating a match against `%{REQUEST_URI}` in a previous `RewriteCond` then using the `%N` backreferences in the following `RewriteCond`.

Comment: That *almost* works... In the 2nd group (after "# check etc"), the first 3 lines work IF the last line is disabled. Similarly, the last line works IF the prev 3 lines are disabled. However, all 4 lines enabled results in Internal Server Error. (PS How do I `@` you ?)

Comment: @gibberish (You don't need to `@` me if you comment on my post) The last rule is going to catch everything, always. I'm not sure why it's there. Are you trying to say that if the previous rule (the one for PDFs) don't match, return a 404 error?

Comment: Hi Jon, that's not quite it either. Even legit pages now are directed to the 404.php page. I'll update the OP to show my current htaccess.

Comment: @gibberish If you want legit pages to get through without going to 404.php (which wasn't clear at all that that was what you wanted, see previous comment) then you need to add conditions to exclude legit requests: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` and `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` before it (answer edited)

Comment: Yes, you mentioned that my questions weren't clear. I apologize for that. I value your generous expertise and will be more careful. So, those lines need to be there again? I assumed that since they were already at the top of the file, those possibilities were covered..? How does it work that they need to be there a second time?

Comment: Your latest changes did resolve the problem, by the way. Seems to be working perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: @gibberish `RewriteCond`'s only affect the immediately following `RewriteRule`, they don't apply to all the rules. So you need to repeat conditions if they need to be applied for more than one rule.

Comment: @jon lin - "You can't do this: RewriteCond ... $...  
Because the backreferences for $1/$2/$3 don't exist yet"

Comment: @jon lin - "You can't do this: RewriteCond ... ...$1...$2...$3...  
Because the backreferences for $1/$2/$3 don't exist yet" - Only half right: indeed you can't do this  ...but not for the reason you stated. Execution of a ruleset jumps ahead to the RewriteRule first, then back to the RewriteConds in sequence, then if necessary the RewriteRule again a second time. So the $n variables _are_ defined at this point. The real reason this doesn't work is that RewriteCond does not do _any_ variable expansion on the right hand side  ...none  ...never.